# How to use TPU on LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to use TPU in colab to speed up the training process of LSTM. But I am keep getting the error: Unable to find the relevant tensor remote_handle: Op ID: 529, Output num: 0

The code and data link are shared below, can anyone please help me to fix this error? Much appreciated :-)

colab code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t1kDuehLNjVhrtmCXdeSAbPcI5Vht90P?usp=sharing
data file（OHLC and indicators，139 columns in total）：https://drive.google.com/file/d/180Ai703VHdICN1VtQl4zWkZw0vHNMoBm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the linked notebook publicly. Presently, other folks can't see its contents.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have changed it.

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial that we have for TPUs with LSTMs? https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shakespeare_with_tpu_and_keras.ipynb